# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir los pasos de una expresión regular?

Tags: java, regex

Me gustaría hacer una traza de la ejecuión de expresiones regulares para ver qué hace en cada paso y poder comparar qué tan bien o qué tan mal se desempeñan varias expresiones regulares usando [java](/questions/tagged/java).

¿Cómo puedo lograr esto?

Para mí sería genial saber cuántos pasos se toma el engine de Java, por lo que seguir usando otros engines es subóptimo desde mi punto de vista,

Si necesitan un ejemplo de lo que hablo, me refiero a por ejemplo la funcionalidad de debug de la página [regex101.com](http://regex101.com)

Comment: La que tu dices regex101 me parece la mejor opcion. La llevo usando meses.

Comment: De hecho así es como le hago, creo y pruebo en regex101 y convierto mediante regexplanet, si lo necesito lo analizo en regexper, pero tal vez ya exista una forma de hacerlo desde y/o para Java más directamente.

Comment: En *regex101* puedes usar uno de los tres sabores disponibles (motores). El motor de Java está basado en el de Perl. No sé de alguna herramienta similar a *regex101* escrita en Java... Pero puedes ① depurar tu aplicación, poniendo algunos puntos de interrupción en la clase `java.util.regex.Pattern` en los lugares que tú creas conveniente. ② También puedes descargar el [código](http://bit.ly/29lVsOz) de la esa misma clase y agregar líneas de código de tu framework de _logging_ favorito en esos lugares .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sólo las primeras 2 opciones son para Java, el resto las incluyo porque son relevantes (aclarando el por qué se incluyen).

---

#### jRegexAnalyser

Genera un *debug* bajo el motor de [java](/questions/tagged/java) y es gratuita y Open Source. No es muy agradable visualmente e incluso cuesta entender qué representa cada uno de los pasos, pero hace lo que estás buscando. Principalmente sirve para ver la cantidad de pasos totales ("Matcher Operations", columna "Op").

**Link:** http://www.schwebke.com/index.php/10/18/

[image: Captura de pantalla de jRegexAnalyer]

---

#### Tiempo de ejecución (*benchmark*)

Si bien medir la cantidad de pasos es un buen comienzo, la única forma de ver realmente cuán eficiente es una expresión regular es midiendo el tiempo que tarda en ejecutarse, comparando 2 o más expresiones regulares con diferentes textos. De esta forma, además se puede considerar el tiempo que se tarda en compilar.

A grandes rasgos, el código sería:

```
int ciclos = 100000;  //Un número grande de repeticiones

long antes = System.nanoTime();  //grabar la hora en que comienza

for (int n=0; n<ciclos; n++)
{
    
    //Poner acá el código con la expresión regular a evaluar
    
}

long despues = System.nanoTime();  //La hora en que termina

//Imprimir cuánto tardó
System.out.println("Tiempo de ejecución: " + (despues-antes)/1e6 + " ms");
```

<kbd>[Ejemplo en ideone](http://ideone.com/84ZsMl)</kbd>

---

#### regex101.com

Desarrollada bajo [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre), **no utiliza [java](/questions/tagged/java)**. Es una de las herramientas mejor logradas visualmente y ayuda enormemente a entender qué sucede a nivel del motor interno de una expresión regular, por lo que vale la pena mencionarla. Sobre todo porque me interesa aclarar lo siguiente:

- Todos los motores de expresiones regulares similares a Perl ("*Perl-like*": PCRE, .Net, Python, Java, Perl, etc.) siguen la misma cantidad de pasos internos teóricos.
- Java y PCRE comparten la mayor parte de las estructuras. Una expresión regular de Java muy probablemente se pueda utilizar en PCRE (sólo [se diferencian en **muy pocas** construcciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/123465/127)).
- La mayor diferencia entre los motores reside en optimizaciones internas que ayudan a reducir la cantidad de pasos a evaluar. Sin embargo, al generar una expresión regular que evalúa menor cantidad de pasos en un motor, casi seguro evaluará menos pasos en otro motor.
- Las herramientas utilizadas para *debug* pueden contar de forma diferente cada paso (1 paso en una herramienta puede ser representada por múltiples pasos en otra herramienta), pero eso no significa que haya mayor procesamiento.

**Link:** https://regex101.com

[image: Captura de la web de regex101.com]

<sub>* Hace un tiempo que está abierta [la solicitud para que regex101 soporte el motor de Java](https://github.com/firasdib/Regex101/issues/54), pero no hay indicios de que se lleve adelante.</sub>

---

#### RegexBuddy

Windows 2000/XP/Vista/7/8/8.1/10 (o en Linux [usando Wine](https://www.regexbuddy.com/wine.html))

**No utliza [java](/questions/tagged/java)**, pero tiene un motor propio que acepta las estructuras y tiene opciones para expresiones regulares de Java (lo emula). Por lejos, la mejor aplicación de escritorio para evaluar expresiones regulares. Lamentablemente, no es gratuita.

**Link:** https://www.regexbuddy.com

[image: Captura de pantalla de RegexBuddy]

Comment: Gracias, regex 101 no me sirve debido a que estaba probando esta expresión regular: `^\(([^a-z\)\p{Punct}\s]{2,})\)\s?(\d[\s\-]?\d+){2,}$|^(\d[\s\-]?\d+){3,}$` no sé si el regexbuddy l acepte. Sería genial que agregaras que el primero es open source y el regex buddy es paga.

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Editada... Justamente tu regex sirve para mostrar que se puede usar PCRE.. Sólo hay que ver en qué estructuras se diferencian y buscar un análogo (lo que remarqué en la descripción de regex101). La cantidad de pasos será indefectiblemente la misma. En concreto, para tu ejemplo, en vez de `\p{Punct}`, se tiene que usar `\p{P}`, que cubre la misma categoría *Punctuation*, tan simple como eso: [demo en regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pT0cA7/1)

Comment: el regexbuddy es solo para windows verdad?

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Windows 2000/XP/Vista/7/8/8.1/10 según lo que dice en [la página,](https://www.regexbuddy.com/download.html) o se puede correr en Linux [usando Wine](https://www.regexbuddy.com/wine.html)

Answer (score -1):

Con Debugexx [link](https://www.debuggex.com/)  puedes analizar los pasos de tu expresión regular. Espero te sirva de algo, saludos!

Prueba con esta expresión en el sitio

\b\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\b

Comment: perdona pero no tiene para Java ni me explica como hacer eso mismo en Java, así que no me sirve tu respuesta, de todas maneras, gracias por tu tiempo.