# Diferencias entre expresiones regulares de Java y PHP

Tags: java, regex

Esta expresión regular funciona en PHP, pero no en Java.

Código PHP:

```
$replace = preg_replace("#(a)#", "o", "hola");
```

Código Java:

```
string.replaceAll("#(a)#", "o");
```

Estoy intentando transformar [este código](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25328690/2436357) de PHP a Java.

Comment: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304925/what-is-the-java-equivalent-to-this-preg-replace) hay una respuesta

Comment: Puedes agregar a la pregunta una cadena de ejemplo y el resultado correcto o al menos el que esperas obtener. Tal vez así sea más fácil de entender donde quieres llegar.

Comment: y [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568168/how-to-do-preg-replace-in-java) hay otra respuesta.

Comment: @GustavoMora el ejemplo de texto está en la pregunta desde el inicio.

Comment: @AdrianaHernández y aquí abajo hay una respuesta mucho más completa ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP utiliza **[delimitadores](http://php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)** para las expresiones regulares. Los `#` al inicio y al final marcan la expresión regular, separándola de posibles modificadores que pueda haber al final. El primer caracter utilizado es el que define cuál es el delimitador en PHP.

En JavaScript por ejemplo, la sintaxis permite sólo el uso de `/` como delimitadores (`/(a)/`).

En Java, las expresiones **no necesitan delimitadores**. Por lo tanto, la expresión debería ser simplemente `"(a)"`:

```
string.replaceAll("(a)", "o");
```

No obstante, en este caso no son necesarios los paréntesis, por lo que alcanza con:

```
string.replaceAll("a", "o");
```

#### Estructuras de PCRE no presentes en el motor de Java

A tener en cuenta para otro regex que quieras llevar de PCRE (el motor de regex de PHP) a Java:

- No se usan delimitadores (descripto arriba).
- Todas **las barras** hay que ponerlas 2 veces, ya que PHP permite un literal de string como `'\bejemplo\b'`, pero en Java no existen, por lo que el string sería `"\\bejemplo\\b"` para que se interprete de la misma forma, y pase el valor `\bejemplo\b` al motor de regex.
- Si tuvieses algún **[modificador](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#field.summary)**, como por ejemplo `/regex/i`, ese modificador lo deberías pasar como 2do parámetro en [Pattern.compile()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile-java.lang.String-int-). Por ejemplo: `Pattern.compile("[a-z]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`.

  Otra alternativa (especialmente si estás usando `String.replaceAll()` que no acepta un parámetro de modificadores) es definirlo dentro de la expresión, como `"(?i)[a-z]+"`.
- Java no soporta **recursión** `(?R)`, en ninguna de sus formas. Para más información, ver el 4to ítem de esta lista.
- Java no soporta **reinicios de coincidencias globales** `\K` (lamentablemente).
- Java no soporta **IFs** (condicionales) `(?(condición)verdadero|falso)`.
- Java no permite **ignorar espacios en blanco** dentro del patrón (modificador `x`), por lo que no ofrece ninguna alternativa de separar e indentar las estructuras de la expresión. No tiene ninguna forma de presentarlo legible, y sólo acepta expresiones continuas.
- Java no soporta comentarios como `(?#comentario)`.
- Java no soporta grupos de reinicio de ramas como `(?|patrón)`.
- Java no soporta clases POSIX como `[:alpha:]`, pero sí los toma como casos especiales de clases Unicode `\p{Alpha}`. También los llama [clases POSIX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#posix) (incorrectamente), pero cuando se usa [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) actúan en conformidad con las recomendaciones de Propiedades de Compatibilidad de Expresiones Regulares Unicode.

Además (menos importantes):

- Java no soporta `\N` como escape de un caracter que no es un salto de línea.
- Java no soporta la sintaxis `\g1` o `\g{1}` como referencia hacia atrás del texto capturado por un grupo, así como tampoco las referencias relativas como `\g-1` o `\g{-1}`
- Java no soporta las sintaxis `(?'nombre'patrón)` o `(?P<nombre>patrón)` para grupos nomenclados, así como tampoco las referencias a grupos nomenclados `\k'nombre'`, `\k{nombre}`, `\g{nombre}`, o `(?P=nombre)`
- Java no soporta más de un grupo con el mismo nombre.
- Java no soporta referencias nomencladas hacia adelante, por lo que no permite una referencia hacia atrás por nombre de un grupo que aún no fue definido, pero que existe más a la derecha en el patrón. Aunque sí permite referencias hacia adelante por número de grupo.

#### Estructuras de Java no compatibles con PCRE

- Java introdujo la [intersección de clases de caracteres](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#classes) `[b-z&&[^eiou]]` que resulta extremadamente práctica (ojalá PCRE también lo adoptara).
- Java permite [clases de caracteres anidadas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#classes), como `[ab[cd]ef]`. PHP en cambio, toma al `[` interno como parte de los caracteres de la clase. Por lo que si quisieras un `[` dentro de una clase, deberías escaparlo como `"[ab\\[cd]"`.
- Existen algunas diferencias en la nomenclatura de clases para scripts, bloques, categorías y propiedades binarias Unicode. A grandes rasgos, la mayoría está presente tanto en Java como en PCRE (o existen alternativas bastante cercanas), pero pueden utilizar nombres diferentes. Ver en [*Unicode support*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#usc).